# having issue with fsockopen while sending mail with swiftmailer

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, swiftmailer

I was playing around the new swiftmailer 4.0.4 using my zend studio embbeded apache server where i can send successfully emails through gmail smtp.
Now that it's was fine and that i decided to use it in real project and this time along using xampp 1.6.8.any time i run the same function there is this error

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\includes\swift\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 243

i've tried to enable ssl from xampp index file it has accepter the certificate but still my error won't disapear.I'm really concerned about this.Can anyone share his opinion or experience? thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think for some reason it started working.i'm not sure about what happened,i reinstall xampp and didn't see the problem anymore.weird.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have the ssl transport installed for php.  Different systems do this in different ways, so I don't know how yours would work.

You can run a quick php app to verify this:

```
<?php

print_r(stream_get_transports());
```

Mine returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tcp
    [1] => udp
    [2] => unix
    [3] => udg
    [4] => ssl
    [5] => sslv3
    [6] => sslv2
    [7] => tls
)
```

If ssl and tls are not there, then your php installation does not have support for them and you need to find a way to fix that.

Comment: Ahhh, so simple yet so effective!